# How to override prepareTranslation method in Drupal\content_translation\Controller in drupal 8?

Tags: 8

I want to override prepareTranslation method using my custom module in drupal 8. You can find this function here(Drupal\core\modules\content_translation\src\Controller\ContentTranslationController.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `hook_entity_prepare_form()` to override the values from `prepareTranslation()` on `$form_state`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to change the $source_translation variable's value of prepareTranslation() function and rest of the things should work as it is in core function.i tried using below code but not geeting output.

Comment: function testmodule_entity_prepare_form(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, $operation, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $source_translation = $entity->toArray();
    $source_translation['title'][0]['value'] = "Hello";
    $source_translation['body'][0]['value'] = "Fine";
}

Comment: $soruce_translation is available in form_state. you could change it there. that's what prepareTranslation() is doing.

Comment: i tried using form_state but not able get values.e.g. ($form_state->getValues('body')) this prints blank array. I am new to drupal 8 can you please help me with small snipate of code?